# How do i not print it twice

Tags: python, function

I'm new to python and experimenting with functions. Here's the sample code that I'm working wtih

```
def menu():
    print(" 1. Divide")

def test1(x,y):
    if y == 0:
        return "The result is undefined"
    else:
        return x/y

num1=int(input("First: "))
num2=int(input("Second: "))

menu()
answer=int(input("Choose: "))

while answer != 0:
    if answer == 1:
        print()
        print(" The result is", test1(num1,num2))
    print()
    menu()
    answer=int(input("Choose: "))
```

When I run the program and input a y value of 0, the result prints twice. How do I make it print once only then return to menu? Thank you

Comment: Does a specific line print twice, or does `"The result is"` print twice? Just change it to `return "undefined"`

Comment: Do you mean that the output is `` The result is The result is undefined`` (and thus contains ``The result is`` twice) or that the output is `` The result is The result is undefined`` `` The result is The result is undefined`` (and thus yields the same output twice)?

Comment: You don't have to use *else*, read about what *return does*.

Comment: @r0ei You don’t *have* to but it makes sense here for symmetry. I wouldn’t write it either in this particular situation (i.e. for guard clauses) but there’s really nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug in your code,
you can simply Change your zero condition to this:

```
if y == 0:
    return "undefined"
```